# GroupBy per 50 games in group | AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, group-by, angular-filters

I have an array of objects (500 objects) and want to GroupBy it 50 games per group (10 groups).

Now data is:

```
var data = [
  { name : "Starburst",
    id : 2614
  },
  { name : "Pipono",
    id : 4587
  },
  { name : "New Bail",
    id : 7827
  } 
  ...
]
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data| groupBy: 'id'"> ... </div>
```

Now I group it by id, and can't find a solution for doing that. 
I know there is a way to do that with "for" loop (add value for every 50th elements 0-50,51-100 ..., and groupBy that value), but it's not the best and fastest way.

How can I realize that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `orderBy:'id'` instead of `groupBy:'id'` is not what you are looking for ?

Comment: @JeanJacques ok, but how I can make groups with orderBy ?

Comment: Hum, I don't think it's possible with `orderBy`, I tought you only wanted to sort them by id. But just to be sure, you want to group them in groups of 50 or if you want to group them by **id** ? Because if you want to group them by id, i think [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/L6cQN/) is doing what you want, no ? Else, you can take a look a [this module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby)

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.sortBy and _.chunk using lodash . Pass the number of items to be grouped together,

```
$scope.itemschunk = _.chunk($scope.itemssorted, 50);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('anExample', []);

app.controller('theController', ['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.test = 'this is a test';
  
  $scope.items = [
    { name:"A",  id: 30}, 
    { name:"B",  id: 20 },
    { name:"C",  id: 200 }, 
    { name:"D",  id: 20 },
    { name:"E",   id: 100 }, 
   
 ];
  
  $scope.itemssorted = _.sortBy($scope.items, 'id');
  $scope.itemschunk = _.chunk($scope.itemssorted, 2);     
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.4.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anExample" ng-controller="theController">

    Hello, {{test}}!
    <ul ng-repeat="group in itemschunk">
      <li ng-repeat="items in group"> name: {{items.name}}, id: {{items.id}} </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Sajeetharan thanks for the answer, but we don't use lodash for this project.

Comment: then you need to use javascript to group the items it will work then